# $rootscope between controllers and refreshing it

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am using a jsonn object to load in data between objects. currently using a factory to return the object and bind it between the controllers. Right now I am making a copy like so :

```
var LevelsHere = $http.get("my.json")
          .success(function(data){
            var dataCopy = angular.copy(data);
            return dataCopy;
          });
return {
    all: function() {
      return LevelsHere;
    }
  };
```

This works fine, but I have a button that I want to call this function and refresh it so It gets a clean copy from the my.json (so any changes are reverted).

Just to clarify, in each controller I call it in into a scope within the controller like so

```
UserService.all().then(function(data){
            $scope.storeHere= data.data;    
        });
```

I am thinking maybe something like a $rootscope might be the way to go because I am sharing between controllers. So  - have the root scope (which is a copy of the json) be shared between controllers. Then when I press my refresh button it would refresh that $rootscope with a fresh copy  of my.json so changes would revert back.

Maybe I could use the method I am trying now? I tried the having the refresh button call the $get again but it wasnt binded to both places so it was only refreshing in one controller.

To quickly review - I have json I'm bringing in and using in 2 controllers with a factory calling it. I want to be able to refresh that so it refreshes in both places.

Here is my attempt at the refresh :

```
 $scope.cancelProcedure = function() {
        //refresh data
        UserService.all().then(function(data){
            $scope.levels = data.data;  

     };
```

The problem with this is it calls the current data, and doesn't refresh with a new call. I'm not sure how to make it refresh in both places. Thanks!!

Comment: Sounds easy, but one question: Do both controllers really need independent copies of the data or the same copy of it? You're angular.copying the data, that's why I'm asking...

Comment: no they dont at all actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you an answer I assume the following:

- There's one resource you want to get `my.json` and update from time to time.
- You want to access and update the data from two (or more) controllers
- You don't want to pollute your `$rootScope`

In that case the ideal solution would be to store the method to get/update the data in the factory as well as the current data. In each controller, where you need that data, you simply inject the factory and assign it to the `$scope`of that controller.

Here's one example:

```
angular.factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {

  var dataFactory={};

  dataFactory.currentData = null;

  dataFactory.update = function () {
    return $http.get("my.json")
    .success(function(data){
      dataFactory.currentData = data;
      return data;
    });
  };

  return dataFactory;

}]);

angular.controller('firstCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataFactory', function ($scope, dataFactory) {
  $scope.data = dataFactory;
}]);

angular.controller('secondCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataFactory', function ($scope, dataFactory) {
  $scope.data = dataFactory;
}]);
```

In your HTML you can then use e.g. `ng-bind="data.currentData"` and `ng-click="data.update()"`.

Further thoughts: If you don't want to put the factory in your controllers `$scope` you might even consider to further break down your logic and create one or two directives that are based on that factory. If that makes sense is not easy to tell with the given information, however.

Comment: If i want the data to populate  initially, can I just set data factory to a $http.get that just runs initially? then i could have the data factory called for the refresh. thoughts? The reason I'm asking is because i had to do a UserService.all().then(function(data){$scope.listTable = data.data;  }); in the controller to make sure the ajax runs to initially populate. thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Typically you would do the initial population either via an `app.run` function or you would use ngRouter or UI-Router's route resolve. Use the latter esp. if you only need it initialised for certain routes. For the start the first solution might be easier to implement. See "Run Blocks" in the [Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

Comment: So I can run the get in .run, and then pass it into the factory?

Comment: Kindof, you inject the factory into a run function and call update `app.run([ 'dataFactory', function (dataFactory) { dataFactory.update(); } ]);` That will be called when your apps starts.

Comment: I hate to be a pain, but could you show me an example of this? I'm still very new. Regardless, very much appreciate the help!!

Comment: That was the precise code you need to run ;-). Just replace `app` with your application variable, if it is not app.